# append few strings at the start and bottom of string coming from file read

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am working on a shell script which is getting data from another program and I am using that variable value to read the content from file and append few things inside those data at start and bottom:

Below is an example:

```
readonly file_location=$location
readonly client_id = $id
readonly client_types = $type_of_client
```

Here $location, $id and $type_of_client value is being passed from another program. Below is an example:

- $location will be full path name like this:
  `/home/david/data/12345678`
- $id will be number: `120`
- $type_of_client will be space separted word: `abc def pqr`

Now inside this location `/home/david/data/12345678` I have files like this: `abc_lop.xml`, `def_lop.xml` and `pqr_lop.xml`. Meaning `_lop.xml` is going to be same always so we can hardcode this. We just need to iterate `client_types` variable and make a file name as shown above and read the whole file into a String for now (or may be if there is any other better way). This I got working as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly file_location=$location
readonly client_id=$id
readonly client_types=$type_of_client

for word in $client_types
do
    echo $word
    file_value=`cat "file_location"/"$word"_lop.xml`
    echo $file_value
done
```

Now I need to do something special like string manipulation in shell script and I am not sure how we can do that. Now whatever value we read from those file I need to append something at the top of it and something at the bottom of it in all those files which we are reading. I need to do exactly same thing as shown below:

For example: If file `abc_lop.xml` is like this after we view it using `vi`:

```
<Hello version="100">

<!-- some stuff here -->

</Hello>
```

I need to make it like this:

```
<hello_function>
<name>Data</name>
<Hello version="100">

<!-- some stuff here -->

</Hello>
</hello_function>
```

As you can see, I added this at the top `<hello_function><name>Data</name>` and I added this at the bottom `</hello_function>`. How can we do this in shell script?

So In general `echo $file_value` should print out above appened values for each of those `client_types`:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly file_location=$location
readonly client_id=$id
readonly client_types=$type_of_client

for word in $client_types
do
    echo $word
    file_value=`cat "file_location"/"$word"_lop.xml`
    // may be do something here?
    echo $file_value // this should print out appended string value both at top and bottom.
done
```

Each of those XML files will be less than 10MB for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to read into a variable if all you're doing is outputting the data. For your main loop:

```
for word in $client_types; do
    echo "$word"
    echo '<hello_function>'
    echo '<name>Data</name>'
    cat "$file_location/${word}_lop.xml"
    echo '</hello_function>'
done
```

Of course, this outputs the concatenation of all the modified files, which may be hard to separate later. But it works.

Edit: To output to separate files:

```
for word in $client_types; do
    fn="${word}"_new.xml
    echo "$word"
    echo '<hello_function>' >>"$fn"
    echo '<name>Data</name>' >>"$fn"
    cat "$file_location/${word}_lop.xml" >>"$fn"
    echo '</hello_function>' >>"$fn"
done
```

Depending, of course, on just what you want in each file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My plan is to use this modified value which has string appended at top and bottom later on for some other purpose. So I wanted to store that in a variable or make a new file with it. Do you think there is any way we can do that?

Comment: It's usually not best to try to store long texts in bash variables. To output each one to a file, you could do something like edit above.

Comment: Ok so that means, `abc_new.xml` file will have appended string at top and bottom right?

Comment: Yes. You can set the filename to whatever, of course.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're quite right, I got carried away quoting.